# Doctrine 2 how to properly map multi-level inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine, nette

I have multi-level inheritance doctrine entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"customer" = "CustomerUser",
 * "admin" = "AdminUser", "stock" = "StockUser"})
 */
abstract class User { ... }

/** @ORM\Entity */
abstract class EmployeeUser extends User { ... }

/** @ORM\Entity */
class AdminUser extends EmployeeUser { ... }

/** @ORM\Entity */
class StockUser extends EmployeeUser { ... }
```

However it does not work this way, fields of EmployeeUser are neither read from database nor persisted.

I've found out that it works when I specify the discriminator map this way:

```
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"customer" = "CustomerUser",
 * "admin" = "AdminUser", "stock" = "StockUser", "EmployeeUser"})
```

it starts to work this way (there is no need to specify discriminator key for EmployeeUser - as it is abstract and will never be instantiated), but

I don't like when magic happen that I don't understand enough :) **so my question is: is this a proper solution? To just let Doctrine know this way that this class is somehow included in inheritance hierarchy? Or should it be done anyhow else?**

I haven't found any mention about how to do multiple level entity class inheritance in Doctrine docs.

Comment: It looks good. What if you define `, "employee" = "EmployeeUser"` in `DiscriminatorMap`? Maybe Doctrine require a discriminator for each child entity. Anyway I don't know if inheritance with multiple levels is supported, can't you use only 2 levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same situation. I need more than one level of inheritance. That in your case is expected behavior, you need to list all of mapped classes in `DiscriminatorMap`.

My case don't have that map because I am using native transformation of ClassName to type key and it's working for classes on all inheritance level.

```
abstract ClassA
abstract ClassB extends ClassA
   - protected someName
ClassC extends ClassB
```

When I save **ClassC** obj I have that property **someName** saved. You can try yourself without discriminatory map and see that all classes are mapped and save.

**EDIT :**

One more thing if you want to avoid multilevel inheritance you can always use `trait` for that. Just group the props to trait and add it to entity. There are good example of trait usage in [**DoctrineBehaviors**](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) bundle. There are using it to import additional capabilities to entities like `blamable`, `loggable` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it is possible to avoid specifying discriminator map. That is the most comfortable solution, of course.